# General Technique for Finding all Ring Homomorphisms Between Two Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm seeing a bunch of questions such as "find all ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/30\mathbb{Z}$," etc., lately, so I'm wondering about whether there's a general method for doing this between any two rings. What steps should I take? I'd appreciate an example in your answer, if you can manage one. Thanks so much!

EDIT: I should be clear here that I'd not necessarily like to see methods that work in every case, and I don't necessarily need a lot of rigour either. I'd just like to see what works for *you* in most practical cases.

Comment: I don't see how to approach this in all generality. But in case of a ringhomomorphismen $\phi: \Bbb Z \rightarrow R$, there isn't any choice. $1_{\Bbb Z}$ maps to $1_R$ and this determines $\phi$ completely.

Comment: It is important to note that, for all ring homomorphisms $\phi:R \rightarrow S$, $\phi(1_R) = 1_S$.  Oftentimes, this will uniquely determine the homomorphism!  For example, this makes it easy to see that there is only one homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: There is no general method, simply because there are way too many rings.

Comment: In the simpler versions of this question you should carefully apply all of the ring axioms and just see what happens.

Comment: I think you guys misunderstand the context. I'm not going for ultra-rigorous proofs-and-theorems methods here. I'd just like to see some techniques that work in common cases. For example, what's a good first step to take? I really don't know if I'm at the level where I'd be seeing any crazy exceptions anyway, so yeah. Rules of thumb. I'll edit my question to make this more apparent.

Comment: @KajHansen I don't think that's quite true. Consider the homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z} / 10 \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} / 10 \mathbb{Z}$ given by $\phi: x \mapsto 2x$.